# migrate APEX to a new database with newer APEX version?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, migration, oracle-apex

what is the best approach to migrate an APEX app to a newer version of APEX (4.2.3) on a fresh installed database on a new server?

is there any straightforward step by step?
I never done that before!

Comment: You could try exporting the app from current db (using apex gui), it will generate a SQL file, and import it in new db (using apex gui). It should work in most cases.

Comment: jepp, this is what I found out later, now it's up and running :-)